# Angular - iframe inner html content same as angular component template,

Tags: angular

In a html iframe i want to display the template from angular component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-steelgauges',
  template:  `
  <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/steelseries@2.0.7/dist/steelseries.bundled.min.js"></script>
  <steelseries-radial size="200" value="65" maxValue="100" gaugeType="TYPE3" frameDesign="GLOSSY_METAL" pointerColor="ORANGE" knobStyle="SILVER" thresholdVisible maxMeasuredValueVisible foregroundType="TYPE4" tickLabelOrientation="HORIZONTAL" useOdometer></steelseries-radial>`,
  styleUrls: ['./steelgauges.component.css']
})
```

like this

```
svgIframeContainer.innerHTML = `here goes template from @Componet`;
```

I want to display the output of the html code, not the HTML code itself. I can bind the HTML code to a variable but then makes it impossible for me to access the proprieties of the gauges I am trying to use.
If i am using the html code in the template i can access it like that.
GaugeValue = 35;
value={{GaugeValue}}

How can i display that template into the inner html?
Or how i can acces that html code when in not in the template?